# PHPMailer not working in web page

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email with PHPMailer, but it's not working for me so far.

On my FTP I've put 2 files, the `class.phpmailer.php` and `sendEMail.php` (this file is created by me), with this content:

```
<?php
require_once('/var/www/vhosts/MYWEBPAGE/httpdocs/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "mail.dom.com"; 
$mail->Username = "smpt@mail.com"; 
$mail->Password = "passwd"; 
$mail->Port = 25; 

$mail->setFrom("my@mail.com", "me", 0);

$mail->addAddress("to@mail.com"); 

$mail->Subject = "test"; 
$body = "Hello World!";
$mail->Body = $body; 

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo ("Invoice could not be send. Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo);
} else {
echo "Invoice sent!";
}

?>
```

I'm missing something? When I execute this file, it shows me nothing, i mean before the if(!$mail->send()) {... It shows me every echo, but after that line, it shows me nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem PHP Mailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681478/problem-php-mailer)

Comment: $mail->SMTPDebug = true;
add this and check what does it shows

Comment: It shows me nothing, maybe i put that line in a non correct position...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you've not read [the readme](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) that tells you what files you need, nor based your code on the examples provided. You've not loaded the SMTP class, nor the autoloader that will load it for you, so as soon as you try to send, it will fail to find the SMTP class. This will be logged in your web server logs like any other PHP fatal error.

Instead of this:

```
require_once('/var/www/vhosts/MYWEBPAGE/httpdocs/class.phpmailer.php');
```

do this:

```
require '/var/www/vhosts/MYWEBPAGE/httpdocs/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

Comment: You are right, I didn't read the readme, after changing what you said, it gave me this error: Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found inclass.phpmailer.php on line 1347. 
I just copied the class.smtp.php and it worked perfectly!
Thanks Synchro!!